# How to import Oracle (C)LOB into another tablespace

Tags: oracle, import, clob, tablespace

I'm importing a database dump from one Oracle 10g installation into another. The source has a layout with several tablespaces. The target has one default tablespace for the user I'm importing the dump into.

Everything works fine, for ordinary tables. The tables are relocated from their original tablespace to the user's default. The problem I'm facing, several tables contain CLOBs with explicit storage directives. That is, they name their storage tablespace. The imp command seems to be unable to relocate these CLOBs to the user's default tablespace.

Is there any hidden command line option for the imp command to relocate the CLOB storage to the user's default tablespace or even one named tablespace?

The error message ORACLE 959 looks like this:

```
IMP-00017: Nachfolgende Anweisung war wegen Oracle-Fehler 959 erfolglos:
 "CREATE TABLE "IF_MDE_DATA_OUT" ("OID" NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "CLIEN"
 "T_OID" NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "TS_CREATE" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL EN"
 "ABLE, "TS_UPDATE" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, "OP_CREATE" VARCHAR2(30) N"
 "OT NULL ENABLE, "OP_UPDATE" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, "IDENTIFIER" VARC"
 "HAR2(50), "TRANSFERTYPE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, "STORE" NUMBER(10, 0"
 "), "DATUM" DATE, "STATE" NUMBER(3, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "DATA_OLD" LONG RAW,"
 " "SUPPLIER" NUMBER(10, 0), "BUYER" NUMBER(10, 0), "GOODS_OUT_IDS" VARCHAR2("
 "4000), "CUSTOM_FIELD" VARCHAR2(50), "DATA_ARCHIVE" BLOB, "DATA" BLOB)  PCTF"
 "REE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 FREELISTS 1"
 " FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "DATA32M" LOGGING NOCOMP"
 "RESS LOB ("DATA_ARCHIVE") STORE AS  (TABLESPACE "DATA32M" ENABLE STORAGE IN"
 " ROW CHUNK 8192 PCTVERSION 10 NOCACHE LOGGING  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 FREELI"
 "STS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)) LOB ("DATA") STORE AS  (TABLE"
 "SPACE "DATA32M" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 PCTVERSION 10 NOCACHE LOGG"
 "ING  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAUL"
 "T))"
IMP-00003: ORACLE-Fehler 959 aufgetreten
ORA-00959: Tablespace 'DATA32M' nicht vorhanden
```

Comment: After all those years I like to share my experience on this. Using datapump instead of just dumping and importing is, as suggested in the answers below, superior to the approach in my question. The solution suggested by Gary works fine with Datapump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pre-create the table using the storage parameters you need, and set the import to ignore errors.

Answer (score 2):

Like Karl, I recommend Datadump but use [REMAP_TABLESPACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#sthref342)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Data Pump Dumps, you could try the remap_schema option to correct the tablespace.